# Incorrect ItemSearchResults generated by "jss graphql:update" command Sitecore 10.2

Tags: jss, graphql

Can anyone help me with this issue?

1. Install NextJs app: `npx create-sitecore-jss nextjs`
2. `jss deploy config`, `jss setup` , `jss deploy app`
3. Install the Sitecore Headless Services package
4. dotnet sitecore login
5. run `jss graphql:update` to update GraphQLIntrospectionResult (added some template)
6. run `jss build` and this step has an error below

```
[ graphql-let ] Running graphql-codegen...
[ graphql-let ] Interface field Item.children expects type ItemSearchResults! but App.children is type ItemSearchResults.
Interface field Item.children expects type ItemSearchResults! but C__AppRoute.children is type ItemSearchResults.
Interface field Item.children expects type ItemSearchResults! but C__Route.children is type ItemSearchResults.
Interface field Item.children expects type ItemSearchResults! but C__StandardTemplate.children is type ItemSearchResults.
```

Many Thanks

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Issue definition:**

The "Interface field `Item.children` expects type ItemSearchResults! but DefaultColumnLayout.children is type ItemSearchResults." errors appear after using the bootstrap command.

**Sitecore Support Resolution**

*Note*: If you cannot upgrade your Headless Services package to `21.0.1`, then follow the support resolution below. Otherwise upgrading to this version will resolve the problem.

When a clean Nextjs application is installed, the edge endpoint is set as the default endpoint (`/sitecore/api/graph/edge`). Based on the error message, I believe the issue happened because of the difference in the `ItemSearchResultsGraphType` and `ItemInterfaceGraphType` (`Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.dll`). The `ItemInterfaceGraphType` class has `NonNullGraphType` for `ItemSearchResults` but the `ItemSearchResultsGraphType` class no.
This code was introduced in the Sitecore Headless Rendering 21, and from the provided data, I assume that you are affected by this behavior.

This behavior was registered as a bug in our bug tracking system. To track the future status of this bug report, please use `reference number 572005`. More information about public reference numbers can be found here: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0853187

Please find the hotfix available at the following URL:
[SC Hotfix-572023-1 GraphQL 7.0.0.zip](https://sitecore1.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/Team-ProductSupport-HotFixes2/EaQ7UNei6JdGqu6fbZQY41UBkGHzATlY-Gh1lWXSAoBy_Q?e=xF3Vst)

Be aware that the hotfix was built specifically for Sitecore 10.3 and Sitecore Headless Rendering 21, and you should not install it on other Sitecore versions or in combination with other hotfixes, unless explicitly instructed by Sitecore Support.

**Enhancements**

I'd also recommend reducing the amount of templates that get generated by GraphQL Template Generation (graphql-let):

```
<!-- REDUCE THE GRAPHQL TEMPLATE GENERATION -->
<api>
  <GraphQL>
    <!-- the defaults section contains config templates that can be reused elsewhere using 'ref' -->
    <defaults>
      <content>
        <schemaProviders>
          <!-- 
                            Edge schema provider. Provides the same response as Edge Delivery GraphQL endpoint
                            Usage: on your endpoint, change your content schema provider to '<content ref="/sitecore/GraphQL/defaults/content/edgeContent" param1="master" />'
                            (where param1 is the database you want to hook to)
                        -->
          <edgeContent type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.EdgeSchemaProvider, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema">
            <!-- 
                                The template predicate defines which templates will have GraphQL types generated for them. This is NOT a security measure - all fields
                                that the API key user/authenticated user can access can be queried by name - but can be used to limit the scope of your GraphQL schema.
                            -->
            <templates type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.TemplateGeneration.Filters.StandardTemplatePredicate, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content">
              <database>$(1)</database>
              <paths hint="list:AddIncludedPath">
                <foundation>
                  <patch:delete />
                </foundation>
                <feature>
                  <patch:delete />
                </feature>
                <project>
                  <patch:delete />
                </project>
                <userdefined>
                  <patch:delete />
                </userdefined>
                <yourProjectFoundation>/sitecore/templates/Foundation/YourProject</yourProjectFoundation>
                <yourProjectFeature>/sitecore/templates/Feature/YourProject</yourProjectFeature>
                <yourProjectProject>/sitecore/templates/Project/YourProject</yourProjectProject>
              </paths>
            </templates>
          </edgeContent>
        </schemaProviders>
      </content>
    </defaults>
  </GraphQL>
</api>
```